# Changing the color of a white stroke

Tags: gimp

My image is a bunch of strokes on a transparent background. The strokes are initially black, I inverted the colors so it's white, is there a way to color it ?

I want the lines to have a pale blue, how do I do that ? All the color effects do nothing because RGB is 255/255/255, there is nothing to change.

I'm thinking about applying something like a sepia filter and once there is color I can change the hue with the hue-saturation tool, it's pretty barbaric and I was wondering if there was another way. Could I for example apply a gradient on *just* the lines ?

Answer (score 2):

If the strokes are on a transparent background, then set the alpha-lock for the layer (checkerboard icon in the `Lock:` line at top of layers list). You can then bucket-fill the whole layer (without using a selection) with the required color, pixels will keep their transparency/opacity.

[image]